# iOS check programmatically if call forwarding is active or not

Tags: iphone, ios

I want a button to be enabled in my app only when call forwarding is active in the device, but am not able to find any solution on the net. Is there any way we can check from an app if call forwarding is active or not?

Comment: whoever rated -1, when I did not find a solution on the net then only I have posted this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. That's all locked down by Apple. If there is a way to detect it, it's only through a private API, which will cause your app to be rejected from the App Store if you use it.